# Invite User Group to a slack public channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, slack, slack-api

I'm using Python 3.7, and Slack Version 4.1.2 (Production). I want to invite a user group that is already present and has many users in it.

What I have tried in python3:

```
def invite_user(scid):
    # invite_url = 'https://slack.com/api/channels.invite'
    # invite_url = 'https://slack.com/api/groups.invite'
    invite_url = 'https://slack.com/api/usergroups.update'
    invite_url_data = {
        'token': auth_token,
        'channel': scid,
        'usergroup': 'SPXXXXXX',
        'name': 'testing'
    }
    r = requests.post(url=invite_url, data=invite_url_data, headers=header)
    print(r.json())
```

Can someone help me get the right API to invite usergroup to a channel?

Comment: it seems to me that you have to get all users from group and then you can send invites to them

Comment: py_dude I know and that is obviously the hard way to do it. But on slack their is just one button to invite user group to public channel. So, I thought their must be an API for this which I could not find in docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inviting the users of a usergroup to a private channel is indeed just one API call. Before that you need to get the users of the usergroup though, which is another API call. And you can't invite yourself, so you need another API call to get your current user ID.

Here is an example script using the official python library for Slack. Note that this will work for up to 1.000 users. If your usergroups are larger you need to add them in chunks.

```
import slack
import os

# init slack client with access token
slack_token = os.environ['SLACK_TOKEN']
client = slack.WebClient(token=slack_token)

# get my own user ID
response = client.auth_test()
assert response['ok']
my_user_id = response['user_id']

# get members of usergroup excluding myself
response = client.usergroups_users_list(usergroup='S12345678')
assert response['ok']
users = [x for x in response['users'] if x != my_user_id]

# add members to private channel
response = client.conversations_invite(
    channel='G12345678',
    users = users
)
assert response['ok']
print(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not how it works in Slack.

You can get members of group by https://api.slack.com/methods/groups.info

Then you can extract user ids list from `group_data["group"]["members"]` for a group you want users to invite from.

After you can do the same a group where you can add them.
After you have 2 lists of users for each group, you can merge them and then make a request:

```
    invite_url = 'https://slack.com/api/usergroups.update'
    invite_url_data = {
        'token': auth_token,
        'channel': scid,
        'usergroup': 'SPXXXXXX',
        'name': 'testing',
        'users': [
            "U060R4BJ4", # here are your users from a merged lists
            "U060RNRCZ"
        ],
    }
    r = requests.post(url=invite_url, data=invite_url_data, headers=header)
```