# Slack bot post mesage to usergroup

Tags: slack, slack-api

I was able to create usergroups and update usergroups.

But there was no method in slack document to post a message to usergroup

https://api.slack.com/methods

I found this function `chat.postMessage` but from the arguments it takes I couldn't find usergroups as an option to post the message to.

https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage

Any help figuring out the appropriate slack api function is appreciated.

Comment: In Slack, I believe you post messages to a channel... IIRC, you'd need to [add a channel for the given user group](https://api.slack.com/methods/admin.usergroups.addChannels) and post to that specific channel.  Alternatively, you can post to a [multi-person direct channel](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#mpdm) -> _"The private group's ID can be retrieved through the conversations.list API method."_

Comment: @blurfus We need to tag specific usergroups the meesage to be sent. Instead of creating multiple channels to notify, we wanted to create usergroups (with team names), to which we can send messages.

Comment: @blurfus I believe you don't know what are usergroups and incorrectly marked the question to be closed. Please check the answer by vadym-nekhai for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) is a correct way to post message into various [conversations](https://api.slack.com/docs/conversations-api), i.e. public channel, private channel, DM or multi-person DM and in the `channel` argument you should provide the correct conversation ID, usually starting from `C**`, `G**`, `D**` followed with alphanumeric symbols. Slack usergroups have `S**` ID and are not considered as conversations. If you'll try to call `chat.postMessage` with `channel=S**` argument you'll get a `channel_not_found` error.

Slack [user groups](https://slack.com/help/articles/212906697-Create-a-user-group) are usually created to make easier users separation for mentioning or mass-inviting them into channels. Most typical, for mentioning. However, their mentioning is kind specific and described in the Slack documentation here: https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#mentioning-groups, i.e. you should include `<!subteam^GROUP_ID>` in your `text` argument or in your text `"type": "mrkdwn"` block.

For example, this code:

```
import logging

from slack_sdk import WebClient
from slack_sdk.errors import SlackApiError

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = WebClient(token="xox**")
    try:
        pt_mention = client.chat_postMessage(channel="C**",
                                             text="Mentioning the <!subteam^S**> user group in plain text.")
        print(pt_mention)

        block_mention = client.chat_postMessage(channel="C**",
                                                # text="Mentioning the <!subteam^S**> user group in the block.",
                                                blocks=[
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "section",
                                                        "text": {
                                                            "type": "mrkdwn",
                                                            "text": "Mentioning the <!subteam^S**> user group in the block."
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ])
        print(block_mention)
    except SlackApiError as e:
        logging.exception(f"Error occurred: {e.response['error']}")
```

produces two sequential messages into the `C**` Slack channel where it mentions `@test` user group with ID `S**`: [on this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmnMf.png).

However, it is not possible to invite a user group into Slack channel with [`conversations.invite`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.invite) call, you should use another method, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58998504/1308939).

Comment: I contacted Slack Support and they mentioned at the moment there is no way to post a message to Usergroups :| But I tested your answer adding `<!subteam^GROUP_ID>` , and it has worked :D. Slack support has been very disappointing mostly.

Comment: Per my experience usually they don't give extensive answers on dev questions, however they are good for solving service problems and pointing to a proper direction. So yes, technically you can't **post** messages to usergroups, but you can **mention** them in existing channels (perhaps an agent wasn't aware about mentions).